# Trace a Hierarchy in a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, hierarchical-data

I have an "Employee" table with an "EmployeeID" column and a column representing Employee's 
   Boss (BossID) which in turn is an employee in the "Employee" table. How can I trace the hierarchy from a given "EmployeeID" to the top most Boss. I do not want a self join approach in this, also I am using SQL Server 2005.

Thank you

Manu

Comment: Are you searching for a kind of stored procedure? I think that's impossible with this database layout without self-joining or using a stored procedure.

Comment: I've added a tag `hierarchical-data`.  This question and related questions have come up scores of times on Stack Overflow.  You can save lots of time by doing a little research before asking.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use some sort of self join basically with the table structure you describe but can use a recursive CTE for this to handle arbitrary depths of hierarchy if that was the concern?

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT EmployeeID, BossId
FROM Employee where EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
UNION ALL
SELECT e.EmployeeID, e.BossId
FROM Employee e JOIN cte ON cte.BossId = e.EmployeeID
)
SELECT EmployeeID 
FROM cte
```